# Determine if Type isn't recognized in System.Text.Json Serialization

Tags: c#, json.net, system.text.json

I'm trying to move from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json and I'm trying to find a way to check if all of my data has been "caught" and is being mapped correctly (re: PolymorphismOptions), since I've used a lot of generic/abstract/interface types.

Is there a way to either:

1. Determine the type that it's trying to convert at the moment?  The `GetTypeInfo()` in JsonTypeInfoResolver seems to only return the "base" type that it finds.
2. Throw an exception or error of some kind, IFF it finds an issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean you want an exception if System.Text.Json tries to serialize a derived type as a base type?  And do you want that only for types serialized as JSON objects, or types serialized as JSON collections as well?

Comment: @dbc - Yes to both, where possible.  Just trying to see if I have any issues.

Comment: I don't recommend doing that with collections.  It's pretty common to declare a property as `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>` and have it implemented as `List<T>`.  Both Json.NET and System.Text.Json only serialize collection items anyway, not collection properties, so the concrete type is generally irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to get the actual type being serialized when the contract for the declared type is being constructed.

However, you can force force System.Text.Json to automatically throw an exception when serializing an unexpected derived type.  To do so, you will need to create a [`JsonTypeInfo` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers) that automatically sets [`JsonPolymorphismOptions.UnknownDerivedTypeHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpolymorphismoptions.unknownderivedtypehandling) to [`FailSerialization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonunknownderivedtypehandling) for all relevant non-sealed types:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> SetupUnknownDerivedTypeHandling(bool objectsOnly = false) =>
        (typeInfo) =>
    {
        // Polymorphism using type discriminators is only supported for type hierarchies that use the default converters for objects, collections, and dictionary types.
        if (typeInfo.Kind == JsonTypeInfoKind.None || typeInfo.Type.IsSealed || typeInfo.Type == typeof(object))
            return;
        if (objectsOnly && typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
            return;
        // TODO: decide whether to fail serialization even for types marked with
        // [JsonPolymorphic(UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = FallBackToBaseType or FallBackToNearestAncestor)]
        if (typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions == null)
        {
            typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions = new() { DerivedTypes = { new(typeInfo.Type) } };
            // TODO: decide whether to fail serialization even for types marked with
            // [JsonPolymorphic(UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = FallBackToBaseType or FallBackToNearestAncestor)]
            // If so, move the setting of UnknownDerivedTypeHandling out of this if statement.
            typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions.UnknownDerivedTypeHandling = JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FailSerialization;
        };
    };
}
```

Then set up your options e.g. as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    // Configure either a DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver or some JsonSerializerContext and add the required modifier:
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver() 
        .WithAddedModifier(JsonExtensions.SetupUnknownDerivedTypeHandling()),
    // Set other options as required.
};
```

Notes:

- Since System.Text.Json always serializes the full concrete type for references declared as `object`, I do not throw an exception in that case.
- It is possible for polymorphic types to configure specific behavior for [`JsonPolymorphicAttribute.UnknownDerivedTypeHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpolymorphicattribute.unknownderivedtypehandling), with `FailSerialization` being the default.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonunknownderivedtypehandling?view=net-8.0):

  | `JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling` value | Effect |
  | --- | --- |
  | FailSerialization | An object of undeclared runtime type will fail polymorphic serialization. **The default.** |
  | FallBackToBaseType | An object of undeclared runtime type will fall back to the serialization contract of the base type. |
  | FallBackToNearestAncestor | An object of undeclared runtime type will revert to the serialization contract of the nearest declared ancestor type. Certain interface hierarchies are not supported due to diamond ambiguity constraints. |

  If some of your types have statically configured behavior other than `FailSerialization` and you want to override that, you can do so by moving the setting outside the `if (typeInfo.PolymorphismOptions == null)` check.
- Personally I don't recommend failing serialization for unexpected collection or dictionary types.  It's common for properties to be declared as `IList<T>` or `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` and be implemented with some concrete type.  If you pass `objectsOnly = false` an exception will be thrown in such cases.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UuHD0I).

Comment: I had done something VERY similar to this, but I didn't have as much experience with the edge cases for the TypeInfo.  This is awesome, thank you!